# two div inline-block, horizontally center first one

Tags: css

I have two div with `display: inline-block;` in order to get them on the same line but i would like to horizontally center the first div and get the second div just to his right. Something like this:

```
page text page text page text page text
page text page text page text page text
               -------- --------     
               | div1 | | div2 |
               -------- --------
page text page text page text page text
page text page text page text page text
```

Comment: You are looking for css grid

Answer (score 0):

Wrap both the div with parent div and give `text-align:center` to that div

```css
.parent{
text-align:center;
}
.a,.b {
display:inline-block;
border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="a">First Div</div>
<div class="b">Second Div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: "First Div" is not horizontally centered

Comment: That's actually not what OP wants. He wants the first `<div>` to be centered, and the second one on the right, but slightly off center